# I want to put bar over a alphabet, but outside in math mode. how do I do it?

Tags: equations

I am trying to write bar symbol with some alphabets inside \begin{equation} \end{equation} like this,

```
\begin{equation}

H \bar{k} 

\end{equation}
```

I have more than one alphabet to give bar. I've showed only one though.

It shows a lot of error as it is in out of math mode. How do I give bar in this equation mode?

Comment: By alphabet do you mean a single letter? And Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't leave blank lines in a `equation` environment!

Comment: I think you are looking for `\={k}`

Comment: thanx! removed blank lines & that worked like a charm!!! anyway thanx again guys, though i am new to latex but i look forward to contribute to the community..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\=` is the text mode equivalent of `\bar`.